# Setting logged in SESSION data - security?

Tags: php, security, authentication

I'm wondering how secure the below code is:

```
if ($username == $user->username && $password == $user->password) {  
    $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = true;
    $_SESSION['userId'] = $user->userId;
}
```

Basically, would there be any way for someone to fake the SESSION variable (besides actually stealing a users cookie)?

Answer (score 1):

Seems fine to me. Just don't store the password or sensitive data in the session in case someone does steal the session id. I believe most of the security risks take place in getting the password to the server securely.

Also, you should store your password hashed at least. Making it (assuming $user->password is hashed using sha1) `sha1($password) == $user->password`

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have the password stored in a salted md5 format.

Comment: "in case someone does steal the session id" --- so what? You've stolen my session_id. How will you get the password?